# I try to create this function in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

this give error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>    near 'TABLE where studentid=id); IF(@sid = 'INDIAN') THEN SET @data:=
>    (s' at line 6

```
    CREATE FUNCTION `dbu_application`.`atudentfee` (id int,code varchar(255))
    RETURNS int(11)

    BEGIN
    SET @sid := (SELECT TYPE FROM TABLE where studentid=id);
    IF(@sid = 'INDIAN') THEN
    SET @data:= (select data from table2 where progcode='code');
    ELSE set $data:=0;
    END IF;
    RETURN @data;
   END$$
```

Answer (score 1):

`TABLE` is a reserved word in MySQL. You can't use it as a name for actual table, unless you put it in backticks

```
SELECT TYPE FROM `TABLE` where studentid=id
```